# Binary classification statistical significance

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, binary-data

Consider a binary classification task and a trained model (e.g. logistic regression) gives  predicted labels. The predictions can be done on a hold out test set or obtained using a cross-validation scheme.

My question: is it possible to put a statistical significance on the prediction performance?

Two possibilities come to mind, either using Fisher's exact test or the McNemar's test (as the labels are paired) on the confusion matrix. Any of these make sense?

Note that this is a different problem than comparing models as described [here for example.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-significance-tests-for-comparing-machine-learning-algorithms/)

**EDIT**
Found permutation tests in this direction: [Permutation Tests for Classification](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11503415_34)

Comment: What are your null and alternative hypotheses?

Comment: @Dave H0: the predictions are random (no association with the true labels). H1: predictions are associated with the true labels.

Comment: What is random guessing to you? Coin flip? Guess based on the probabilities of each class in the pooled data?

Comment: @Dave thanks! I did not think about this before. But I think using class base probability will be conservative, so will go with that. Do you agree?

Comment: I think using base class probability is akin to using the pooled mean in linear regression and comparing our model to that via $R^2$. In the absence of predictors, guess according to your knowledge. Then allow the model to tighten up those guesses. So I would say that using the base class probability would be the most naïve *reasonable* way to make predictions. What do you mean, though, about it being conservative?

Comment: @Dave by being conservative I mean that it will generally give higher P value compared to the other option is coin flip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107474/discussion-between-dave-and-datadoh).

Comment: @Dave sorry I don't manage to get into the chat on my phone, don't have access to my laptop right now.

Comment: Have you considered plotting the curve of a random classifier on a ROC plot? You can refer to this: https://medium.com/@xzz201920/roc-and-auc-51940e57fd15